# Add vector OSM XYZ layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, vector-tiles, vector-layer, xyz-tiles

[Marble](https://apps.kde.org/marble/) has an option to display OSM's vector map. Is there a way to add this vector map into QGIS?

I see the raster XYZ URL format is:

> https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Is there a similar server but for SVG (vector) tiles?

Comment: Vector tiles are typically just "data in some schema" stored in "some container file format".  Without details of each it's difficult for people unfamiliar with Marble to comment - it'd be worth linking to what details you do have from the question.

Answer (score 1):

For OSM vector files to be used in QGIS the following url:

> `https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer`

can be added in the browser add 'ArcGIS Vector Tile Service Connection' [Vector Tiles]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `OpenStreetMap_v2` the most recent version?

Comment: from ESRI yes, updated monthly. See https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fae788aa91e54244b161b59725dcbb2a

Answer (score -1):

The OSM wiki [Vector tiles#Providers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles#Providers) lists several providers—e.g.:

[MapBox](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/vector-tiles/#retrieve-vector-tiles):

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{tileset_id}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.{format}
```

[Maptiler](https://docs.maptiler.com/cloud/api/tiles/#xyz-tiles):

```
https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/{tilesId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.{format}
```